Can we use "define sth as clause..." AS "define sth as sth"?
From StoneyB on hiatus 's answer in What is the meaning of "as with" in the following sentences?

The first example, defining snap as it is used in utterances like “Her
eyes snapped with anger”, seems uncertain whether flash is literal or
metaphorical.

Is defining snap as it is used in utterances like “Her eyes snapped with anger” grammatical ?
Dictionary definition says 'define sth as sth',not 'define sth as clause'.

There's no problem with this.  Do you understand what it means?

@James K defining snap as “Her eyes snapped with anger”. But I don't know the usage of 'as it is used in ....'

I mean do you understand "Her eyes snapped in anger"?  It's clearly a figurative use of "snap",  it gives you an image, and doesn't use the "dictionary definition" of snap.

@James K It seems you don't understand my question. Usage of 'as' not meaning.

Are the square brackets in the original, or did you add them? I would expect as to be inside the brackets as well.

@Kate Bunting,I added it, so 'as' should be recognized as 'in the way in which' with the part of speech of 'conj' not 'prep'.

As belongs with it is used. The sentence talks about defining 'snap' in the way that it is used in sentences like 'Her eyes snapped with anger'.

The question isn't clear. Please quote the actual complete sentence rather than putting your own text in square brackets, and give its source. We can't evaluate it otherwise.

@Stuart F Added it.

Note that StoneyB's cited text doesn't actually define "snap" at all. It simply refers to the definition that would apply (if anyone wanted to supply a definition) in the cited usage context. StoneyB is making the point that in such a definition, it might be open to interpretation whether the word "flash" should be classed as a literal or a metaphorical usage.
